# For which reason "in" not work to know if string exists in array?

Tags: javascript

```
1 in [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4]
```

Returns `true`, as expected.

```
'a' in [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4]
```

Returns `false`, but I hoped `true`

For what reason does it happen? Must be because a string be an object?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` tells you if a property of that name exists, not if any of the properties have a *value* that match it.

Your array would look something like:

```
{ 
    "0": 1, 
    "1": 2,
    "2": 4,
    "3": "a",
    "4": 4,
    // and various features from Array
}
```

There's no "a" on the left hand side.

Use [`indexOf` to search for values in an array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Shouldn't the indexes be integer as `indexOf` returns number?

Comment: @Tushar — Property names are always strings. Places where you can type a Number (there is no integer type in JS) get converted to strings when used as a property name.

Answer (score -1):

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 4];
```

`1 in ar` checks the existence of `ar[1]`, not the fact that one of the array elements is `1`.

`'a' in ar` does the same for `ar['a']`.